# How to select female, male, and both selections as ''All''

Tags: r, shiny

How to select female, male, and both selections as ''All''.

This is the code in the radioButtons
[image]

```
 radioButtons(
          "Buttons",
          "Sex",
          choices = c(levels(Titanic$Sex), 'female', 'male', 'All'),
          selected = 'male'
        ),
```

Comment: The changes should be made in the radioButtons section but when I click All on the app, nothing appears.

Comment: Please don’t post [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72742993/adding-a-all-selection-which-chooses-both-characteristics-male-and-female-in-r).

Comment: If you can give a solution please do!